# Addthis facebook getUserID

Tags: facebook, addthis, userid

I would like to know if its possible to get the facebook userid in the event callback when you click a button using the addthis share buttons.

i'm using the facebook like button in the xbfml fashion like this:

```
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"">
```

i'm also tracking the event with:

```
addthis.addEventListener('addthis.menu.share', eventHandler);
```

and tracking the result with:

```
console.log(evt.data);
console.log('Service: ' + evt.data.service);
```

evt.data returns:

```
element: Object {}
service: "facebook_like"
url: <my url>
```

So, is there any way of getting the fbid in the callback?

Thanks.